# Changed domain for Wordpress site, but no longer loading resources (trying to load resources on old domain)

Tags: wordpress

I changed my domain from http://www.troov.co/blog to http://www.troov.com/blog

Despite changing the Wordpress Address URL and Site Address URL to www.troov.com/blog, it's still trying to load resources from www.troov.co, and so none of the styling or images displays correctly.

I'm guessing there is a setting somewhere which I haven't changed, but unfortunately despite trying, I can't locate it!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find/replace URLs in the rest of the database, i.e. the wp_options table as a whole, the GUIDs of posts, etc., not only for the two main site URL options you changed (Wordpress Address URL and Site Address URL).

Don't do a find/replace in a text database dump; that will break serialized data, i.e. theme options, widgets, etc. You can do a find/replace in the database with queries using phpmyadmin or adminer, but that can still break serialized data.

You must use a tool that correctly de-serializes and re-serializes php data. Use [WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool.](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) It's very popular and works well.

Also check to see that the domain is not hardcoded in `wp-config.php` or the theme's `functions.php` file in the format

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Remove those directives, if found. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that the domain was hardcoded in the `wp-config.php`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the main url from http://www.troov.co/blog to http://www.troov.com/blog in *Admin Tool -> Settings -> General* or directly in the wp_options table, check the option_value field for corresponding siteurl and home option_name field records.

Probably, you have your domain address hardcoded. You can check this in your theme files, how url for images are generated, etc.